# Forms with Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, csrf, symfony

I am struggling with forms in Symfony 3.

The setup is pretty simple.

A. controller in /src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/MovieAdminController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

use AppBundle\Form\MovieFormType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class MovieAdminController extends Controller
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @Route("/movie/new", name="admin_movie_new")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(MovieFormType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($form->getData());
        }

        return $this->render('admin/movie/new.html.twig', [
            'movieForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

B. formtype in /src/AppBundle/Form/MovieFormType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MovieFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('genre')
            ->add('budget');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

    }

}
```

C. twig template:

```
[...]
{{ form_start(movieForm) }}
{{ form_widget(movieForm) }}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

{{ form_end(movieForm) }}
[...]
```

When I submit the form I keep getting the dreadful message "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."

The form does have the hidden field with the token, but it seems to me that the submitted value is different from the value in session.

in the profiler I see:

POST Parameters

```
movie_form  [ title => blabla, genre => blabla, budget => 123, _token => e-zvG9Gk0qBJzTE4exIK3K5katq9-_AFEAWyTptx7rg ]
```

SESSION Parameters

```
_csrf/movie_form    QxbBQISsIwQLUlwWwAPa_l2xZbB5zqdHOwaOxrNAHtg
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.

All was due to Symfony session handling. I am working with a Vagrant VM (Debian Jessie) and the standard setting in app/config/config.yml does not work (see this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/985) on Github).

It's only one little change: search the line

```
handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
```

and change it to

```
handler_id:  ~
```

And everything started working 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You must put ad the end of your view but before `{{ form_end(movieForm) }}` `{{form_rest(movieForm)}}`. your code will look like

```
{{ form_start(movieForm) }}
{{ form_widget(movieForm) }}
{{form_rest(movieForm)}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

{{ form_end(movieForm) }}
```

Comment: thank you Ricardo, but as you can see in my own answer, the problem was due to the session handling setting. thank you again for your help.